# What template usage is better in factorial

Tags: c++, templates

From the wikipedia I see an example of generic programming for factorial calculation done like below:

```
template <int N>
struct Factorial 
{
    enum { value = N * Factorial<N - 1>::value };
};

template <>
struct Factorial<0> 
{
    enum { value = 1 };
};
```

and from my side I wrote the code like below :

```
template <typename T>
T factorial(T n)
{ 
  T x;

  if (n == 1)
    return 1;

  x = n * factorial(n-1);

  return x;
}
```

I read in the stackoverflow that enum is what is used in generic programming, but did not find arguments for the reasons.

So why using enum is better and what if the second code has pitfalls.

Comment: The first is calculated at compile time, the second at run time.

Comment: @ChrisMM : sorry for my question but how could I distinguish between what if a peace of code will be calculated at run time or compile time. I thought as both templated will be compile time.

Comment: These two code samples solve different problems. You can't use the first one easily with user provided inputs and you can't use the second at all at compile time.

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd In the second example `T` is resolved at compile time but the function itself depends on `n` which is a run-time value. The first is calculated at compile time because the value is template arguments which necessarily can only be calculated at compile time.

Comment: Just because some code is a function template doesn't mean it can or will be completely evaluated at compile time. It only means that you can create different varieties of that function using compile-time information (your choice of `T`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first was required when constexpr functions didn't existed yet. Enums were the only way to store values useable at compile time when `constexpr` didn't existed. Nowadays, you could implement the same template based computation using `static constexpr` instead of enums. Also the first is not generic by type, it's for `int` only.

The second is generic by type using a template but executed at runtime only.

Of course, templates are instantiated at compile-time but the instantiated code is runtime only by default.

With `constexpr` function, you can write the same code for runtime and compile time:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr T factorial(T n)
{ 
  T x{};

  if (n == 1)
    return 1;

  x = n * factorial(n-1);

  return x;
}

int main() {
    int compiletime[factorial(2)];

    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    int runtime = factorial(n);
}
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 : and so using enum mocks the constness of `constexpr` !

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd Indeed!

Comment: Thank you both for the valuable answers and comments.